# Dynamic Dropdown from Mongo

Tags: javascript, ruby, mongodb

I have a mongoDB with a DB = Staff and a collection = records. It contains a list of employees, and one of the fields is workgroup and it has items like "management", "union", "support staff", etc.

I want to populate a dropdown list with the values of the workgroup field and then use it to retrieve all records from the specified value selected in the dropdown.

I am using Ruby and I can retrieve the values ok (I can see them in the console), but they do not populate the dropdown list.

This is my Ruby statement:

```
get '/workgroup' do
  Record.all.to_a.collect(&:workgroup).uniq.to_json
end
```

My attempt at the javascript is:

```
<script>
 //var json = 'http://localhost:4567/api/v1/workgroup';

 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON("/api/v1/workgroup",function(obj)
   {
         $.each(json.records,function(key,value)
         {
             var option = $('<option />').val(value.workgroup);
        $("#dropDownDest").append(option);
})
  })

         });

</script>
```

Once I get the information in the dropdown, I want to use it to return all records with that workgroup value to a table. I haven't figured that part out yet. One step at a time!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Within your `$.getJSON` call back you are referencing `json.records`, but there is no `json` variable or object.

The argument you are passing to the callback is `obj`. I think you really want to be doing `$.each(obj, function(key, value)...`

Comment: Thanks! I think you are on the right track. At least now, the drop down list expands when I click on it, but there are still no values in it. I looked at the data being returned and it appears to be an array of strings. It looks like this

["Management", "Union", "Support Staff"]

Could that be causing the problem, since it isn't in a strict JSON key/value syntax?

Comment: In your ruby code you are calling `.collect(&:workgroup)`, so it's only returning a list of work groups.

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in your javascript, or use some alerts, to see what the `obj` value looks like, and what the `key` and `value` are being set to. If you just replace `json.records` with `obj` I don't think that's going to fix it, because you are still doing `value.workgroup`, but in this case `value` is just a list of strings, there's no `workgroup` key or method to call.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll google around and try to fix it! I appreciate the help.